# silverlight barseries colors

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, charts

I can't seem to figure out how to bind the color of the datapoints in my BarSeries.  I see tons of posts about this using control templates and BarDataPoint.  I can't seem to figure how to attach the template.

```
<charting:Chart Name="chtIndPerformance" Canvas.Left="464"  Canvas.Top="275" Height="363" Width="444" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#11306A" Foreground="White" >

        <charting:BarSeries IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=industryTitle}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=indReturn}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <charting:BarSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding myColorProperty}" />
                </Style>
            </charting:BarSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </charting:BarSeries>
    </charting:Chart>
```

can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it, I'll use Expression Blend